# Why would a C# method not return a value?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, void

It's easy to understand why `method()` returns a value - but I can't wrap my head around the concept of a method that doesn't return a value.

```
static void PrintName(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    Console.Writeline($"{firstName} {lastName}");
}
```

This method prints `firstName` and `lastName` to the console, but doesn't return a value. Why would a programmer do that? How is it used?

Comment: The point of a method that doesn't return a value is to rely entirely on the side-effects of that method - like writing the `Console` (as per your example) or saving a file as a another example.

Comment: The code in the question *already answers* the question. Could you please clarify why `Console.WriteLine` does not demonstrate such method or maybe how code in the question does not show "how is it used then"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, the code doesn't already answer the question

Comment: *I can't wrap my head around the concept of a method that doesn't return a value.* - and yet you've used a method that doesn't return a value - do you really have a problem with wrapping your head around `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of methods that return a value as if they're an answer to a question:

Q: What's today's date? 
A: April 15, 2022.

```
public string GetDate() { return DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); }
```

Think of methods that don't return a value as an action executed based on a request.

Person 1: Please put this mug on the table. 
Person 2: *puts the mug on the table* - *doesn't need to say anything*

```
public void PutMugOnTheTable(Mug mug) { Table.Items.Add(mug); }
```

See also this related post on Software Engineering SE: 
[When and why you should use void (instead of e.g. bool/int)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/67707)

Comment: Thank you, this is the clearest example so far! Your explanation makes total sense and does connect the dots for me now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the name, there is no reason to return the value.
If you create or build something, you can expect results, but it is difficult to expect results for internal operations such as Add, Remove, Print, etc.

Comment: When we Add, Remove or Print, don't we get results of things being added, removed and printed? Or it is merely an action/output. I know the answer, but would love to benefit from your explanation.

Comment: @SuffianSamsuddin It depends on how is the class or the very method is intended to be used, or what the requirement (from customer, etc.) is. For your example in original post, the `PrintName(...)` prints parameters in console and that's it. What do you need it to return? Maybe like... if you want it to return the combined names, sure, add it to return. It all depends on what you need from the method you're coding.

Comment: There's a `BigDecimal` in Java, and it does calculation like `num.Add(anotherNum).Divide(...).Multiply(...)` and so goes on. If it doesn't return value after `add`, `divide`, etc., then the coding process around `BigDecimal` will have big difference.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang thanks for the explanation. Definitely extends the clarity from the best answer given.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reasons to not return a value. Your example is a very good one. What possible information would you want to have returned from that method? It's a self-contained function that doesn't manipulate any data or affect the state of the program. Return values are used to pass back results of operations, statuses, modified data, etc. For situations in which you don't need anything back there's `void`.

Now you might think that you'd rather have `PrintName` return a boolean for success, but the method as written is just going to work. Putting in a return statement and consuming the returned value is added code complexity for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Logarr! Your explanation helps.

So say we have a method called DoStuff(). You're saying the "stuffs it can do" are:

(a.) output something, and/or
(b.) return a value.

Is there anything else a method can do?

Comment: @SuffianSamsuddin If you want to get very technical, methods don't have to do anything or return anything. An empty method can be called and is valid if it has `void` as a return type. But realistically all methods do _something_, but not all of them have to return anything. Technically when you do `{ get; set; }` on properties for a class, the compiler creates a `void` set method. It puts the value you give it in storage and doesn't return anything. So really you're using them frequently without even seeing them.